# Call Buttons like Android 4.0 app

Tags: java, android, button

how can I make buttons like the buttons for numbers in the android 4.1 contact app and higher so like Number, than write mobile for example and then another button? There's a screenshot what I mean:

[image: http://imgur.com/Zq7MXse]

Ok thanks for someones help :)

Comment: Which buttons are you talking about?

Comment: Button??? Where is it hiding..

Comment: I mean the button where stands MOBIL and 849 and where the SMS symbol is :)

Comment: I guess that's an image set as background.

Comment: Do all now know what i mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectors to change the image and background when the user interacts with it. Combined with an onClickListener you'll get the desired affect.

icon_selector.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:dither="true">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_bg_active"/>

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_bg_active"/>

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_bg_active"/>

    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_bg_inactive"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_bg_inactive"/>

</selector>
```

Set the background to the selector

```
myIcon.setBackground(icon_selector);
```

And attach the click listener...

```
myIcon.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
     @Override public void onClick (final View v) {
           // do something interesting here
     }
});
```